# How to enable support for Teams Apps with Static Tabs in the "NEW" Teams Desktop client?

Tags: microsoft-teams

Microsoft has launched a NEW Teams Desktop client.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/new-teams-known-issues

(Apparently there isn't a formal or informal name for this release of the client so will just call it the "NEW Teams Desktop Client"  This is not an version update but a fundamentally new client. If anyone has been told how to unambiguously refer to this client in bug reports or questions or feedback, please leave a comment)

We have several dozen deployments of a custom Teams App that relies on personal scope Static Tabs ( https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/what-are-tabs?tabs=desktop%2Cdesktop1%2Cpersonal ).  These Static Tabs are configured using Teams App Manifest files.

What changes to Teams Apps Manifest files, if any, are needed for these tabs to surface on the NEW Teams client.  These static tabs work fine on the classic Desktop Teams Client and the Web Teams client, but DO NOT APPEAR on the NEW Teams client.

If this is a known limitation of the NEW Teams Desktop client, it is not called out in the Known Issues in the URL shared above

Relevant abstract of Manifest.json  (works in current/legacy Teams Desktop Client, not in the NEW Teams client)

```
"$schema":  "https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/json-schemas/teams/v1.11/MicrosoftTeams.schema.json",
"manifestVersion":  "1.11",
```

[image]

Update:

@Meghana-MSFT Based on your comment, we tried again and it turns out there is a bug in the new Teams client based on how the App was launched. If App is launched from an Teams Admin pinned icon (Set up Policy) then the static tabs display. Same when App is launched by searching from the Apps menu or from the ... menu in the navigation rail. However if App is launched from Chat / Activity Tab from an existing session, the tabs disappear. Even popping out the App in new tab using the popout icon seems to make no difference in this case. I am updating the question with screenshots

[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you please tell us if you are not able to see the tab entirely or tab is not loading? We checked this at our end by creating a sample tab app by adding "https://www.bing.com/" in contentUrl. We have uploaded this app in Classic teams and pinned the app. Then switched to new Teams and app is loading properly.

Comment: You have manifest schema version set to "1.11" but the manifest version set to "1.16". Not sure if this can cause the problem, though. But you better keep them in sync.

Comment: @Meghana-MSFT  Based on your comment, we tried again and it turns out there is a bug in the new Teams client based on how the App was launched. 

If App is launched from an  Teams Admin pinned icon (Set up Policy) then the static tabs display.  Same when App is launched by searching from the Apps menu or from the ... menu  in the navigation rail.

However if App is launched from Chat / Activity Tab from an existing session, the tabs disappear.   Even popping out the App in new tab using the popout icon seems to make no difference in this case.

I am updating the question with screenshots

Comment: Have updated the question with additional screen shots since cant add images in comments @Meghana-MSFT

Comment: @Nikolay - thanks for catching that.  It was a typo in the cut and paste here.  I have edited the question as in the actual manifest file both schema and manifestversion were matching.

Comment: @Ennova - Could you please confirm if you are able to see the tabs in Teams classic from chat.

Comment: @Meghana-MSFT Yes. Teams classic works fine.   See my update section in the question; it seems to be a bug in new Teams where depending on where the App is launched from makes a difference whether the Static Tabs will show or not.

Comment: We are able to repro this issue, we have raised a bug. We will keep you posted on the updates. Thank you.

Comment: @Ennova - We received an update from the engineering team, currently personal tabs are not added to 1:1 bot chat, this is considered as a feature request. Please note that the tabs are available in the personal app view which is the main entry point for app interactions.

Comment: @Meghana-MSFT  This is a regression from the current Teams client behavior, not a new feature.    On the last sentence, can you explain what you mean by personal app view? Once the App has been launched and is already showing in recent chats, it is unreasonable to expect the user to keep returning to a new launch point to get the tabs back.   Again, this is a regression from the current Teams client behaviour

Comment: Team would add the support for static tabs in chat in new Teams as well, that is why I mentioned it as a feature.  By personal app means from Apps menu or from the ... menu in the navigation rail.

Comment: @Meghana-MSFT do we have an update on this now that new Teams is getting aggressively rolled out?

Comment: Apologies for the inconvenience caused to you. We currently do not have any ETA/update to share with you.

Comment: Microsoft is going to force a migration to new Teams in about 5 weeks (March 31, 2024).  When is this bug going to be fixed?  Do you intend to cripple the use of all ISV bots with chat component?    @Meghana-MSFT

Comment: @Ennova - The feature should be fully rolled out as of a few weeks ago. Could you please confirm whether or not you can see the tabs now?

Comment: No, we do not. If Teams App is initially invoked from  App menu all static tabs plus Files are visible. Once the user starts chatting with the Teams App they will use the Chat Pane Navigation rail from that point on.  The static tabs disappear in that case.

Also, this issue is still shown open in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/resources/teams-updates#known-issues

Personal static tabs aren't supported in one-on-one conversations with bots in the new Teams client. However, users can open their app from the app bar in Teams and view the personal static tabs.

Comment: We will check internally and get back to you.

Comment: Engineering team has asked to [file a bug](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/admin/get-help-support?view=o365-worldwide) and [submit logs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/log-files#debug-logs) so that they can narrow down the issue.